# Jquery Expand Collapse all divs on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this has been asked a thousand times but I'm still having trouble figuring it out. I have a simple according following [this tutorial](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-accordion-w-css-and-jquery/) and I'm trying to add an "expand/collapse all" link. I have found a way to expand all but can't figure out how to collapse them. The problem with a `slideToggle()` solution is if I open one then click the link it will close/open all of them but the one that was previoiusly active.

I set up a [jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/4SVXt/)

Here is an overview of the code:

**HTML:**

```
 <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Div 1</a></h2>
     <div class="acc_container">
         <div class="block"> Yay content!</div>
</div>
 <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Div 2</a></h2>
     <div class="acc_container">
         <div class="block">More Content, Score!</div>
      </div>
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Div 3</a></h2>
     <div class="acc_container">
          <div class="block">Even More Content</div>
     </div>

<a href="#" class="acc_expand-all">Expand/Collapse All </a>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//Set default open/close settings
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers

    //On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
            $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
//Remove all "active" state and slide up the immediate next container
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor

});


    $('.acc_expand-all').click(function(){
    //expand all on click

     $('.acc_trigger').addClass('active').next().slideDown();

    return false;


   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check in your expand/collapse handler to see how many are open, etc., something like this ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SVXt/23/)):

```
$('.acc_expand-all').click(function(){
    var all = $('.acc_trigger'),
        active = all.filter('.active');

    if (all.length && all.length === active.length) {
        // All open; close them
        all.removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    }
    else {
        // At least some are closed, open all
        all.not('.active').addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Regarding your question in the comments, you can check to see whether you should be in "exclusive" mode or not by checking how many are open and whether the clicked one is open, e.g. ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SVXt/30/)):

```
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        thisActive = $this.hasClass('active'),
        active;

    // If this one is active, we always just close it.
    if (thisActive) {
        $this.removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    }
    else {
        // Is there just one active?
        active = $('.acc_trigger.active');
        if (active.length === 1) {
            // Yes, close it
            active.removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
        }

        // Open this one
        $this.addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something like that but i was trying to use `hasClass()` instead of `all.lenght` Do you know a way to get rid of the jumpyness (sp) when you expand all then click on only one div?

Comment: @BandonRandon: That will depend on what you want to have happen in that case. For instance, if you want to just close the one clicked (which is what I'd do), you can check to see how many are active and if it's more than one, just do that.

Comment: I was thinking just set the one clicked to a state of `show()` and then let all the others slide up.

Comment: @BandonRandon: I added one possible solution for the jumpiness based on what I thought you might like, it may not be exactly what you want but should get you going the right way.